# XMLHttpRequests Not Being Logged In Chrome Console

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

This is a strange one, and I'm wondering am I just missing something small. For some reason none of my successful XMLHttp requests are showing in my console on Google Chrome.

I have enabled "Log XMLHttpRequests" in the console, and it does work on other sites, but not on a jQuery Mobile app I'm building which is local on my machine. It seems to log when they are failed requests, but not successful ones.

I'm doing a simple enough AJAX request

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){          
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://www.xxxxx.ie/api/get_recent_posts",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        ajax.parseJSONP(result);
    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
    }
  });         
});
```

And I can see in the network tab of the console that the request has fired, waiting time and then the 200 response status, so any ideas why it's not showing up in the console? I have also tested this with the site hosted and it's the same issue. It's not critical but I'd like to have it so I can tell if prefetching is working etc..

I'm using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: because you are making `jsonp` request which is essentially a script request

Comment: Ah right that explains it so, sorry if that was a bit of a silly question..

Comment: Try `jqxhr` object `beforeSend : function (jqxhr) { jqxhr.loadtime = $.now(); }, success : function (result, textStatus, jqxhr) { console.log(textStatus, jqxhr.status, $.now() - jqxhr.loadtime)}`